# TypeError: rxjs_1.lastValueFrom is not a function

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am building an api using nestjs. After adding the typeorm and pg dependencies and adding the `TypeOrmModule.forRoot({})` code in `app.module.ts` like shown below.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { CoffeesModule } from './coffees/coffees.module';

@Module({
  imports: [CoffeesModule, TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    username: 'postgres',
    password: 'xxx',
    database: 'postgres',
    autoLoadEntities: true,
    synchronize: true
  })],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I get an error `TypeError: rxjs_1.lastValueFrom is not a function` with but no error when I exclude `TypeOrmModule.forRoot({})`.

What could be the reason for the error ?

Comment: maybe: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/7468

Answer (score 138, accepted):

If you're using Nest v8, RxJS version 7 is used, which no longer has a `toPromise()` method for Observables, so Nest uses the `lastValueFrom` method instead. If you're receiving this error, you probably need to update your `rxjs` dependency to >7.

```sh
npm i rxjs@^7
yarn add rxjs@^7
pnpm i rxjs @^7
```

Pick your flavor of package manager and have at it.

In the last update of NestJS, when is used cli to initialization of project this error is throw.

Answer (score 18):

## The real answer

The issue is conflict with nest version.. anyone who see this - just make sure all your nestJs packages are of version 7 or 8 - don't mix them. especially those:

- @nestjs/common
- @nestjs/core
- @nestjs/typeorm

from here: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/7468#issuecomment-876174870

Answer (score 9):

update "@nestjs/typeorm": "^7.1.5" in package.json and enter npm i and restart server

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this post because i had this issue when running migration

> Error during migration run:
> /app/node_modules/rxjs/src/internal/util/identity.ts:43 export
> function identity(x: T): T { ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

The cause of the issue was a bad entities path property.

Instead of having: `entities: [__dirname + '/src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],`

I had: `entities: [__dirname + '/**/*entity{.ts,.js}'],`

So be aware that this can cause some unexpected errors.